# Consutla MySql en c#: IS NULL

Tags: c#, mysql, datatable

quisiera una ayudita al respecto, hago esta consulta en c#:

```
            String consulta = "Select * from detallepedido where Libros_IdLibro = " + IdLibroObtenidoDetalle + " and FechaDevolucion IS NULL";
```

Y me arroja que tengo error de sintaxis en FechaDevolucion IS NULL.

Pero si hago la misma consulta en MySql Workbench no me da error.

Como podría hacer la consulta? necesito que la consulta me arroje las filas que corresponden Libros_IdLibro (le paso ese parametro) y que además filtre por FechaDevolucion cuando está vacia.

Les agradezco de antemano.

Edito:

Capturo el "IdLibroObtenidoDetalle" desde un combobox aquí:

```
 DataTable comprobarLibro2 = li.comprobarLibro2(Convert.ToInt32(this.cmbPrestaLibro.SelectedValue));
```

paso el parametro al comprobarLibro:

```
public DataTable comprobarLibro2(Int32 IdLibroObtenidoDetalle)
    {
        libroBD = new LibroBD(this);
        return libroBD.comprobarLibro2(IdLibroObtenidoDetalle);
    }
```

le metodo comprobarLibro2 (completo) es:

```
public DataTable comprobarLibro2(Int32 IdLibroObtenidoDetalle)
    {
        if (this.cn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            this.cn.Open();
        }

        DataTable tablaComprobacion2 = new DataTable();
        String consulta = "Select * from detallepedido where Libros_IdLibro = " + IdLibroObtenidoDetalle + " and FechaDevolucion IS NULL";
        MySqlDataAdapter adaptador = new MySqlDataAdapter(consulta, this.cn);
        adaptador.Fill(tablaComprobacion2);
        this.cn.Close();
        return tablaComprobacion2;
    }
```

Al lanzar la ejecución, ahora me da este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El código se bien, la pregunta sería si la variable trae algún dato ya que si viene vacía podría causar algún conflicto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución finalmente es agregar a la cadena de conexión

```
Convert Zero DateTime=True
```

Para permitir la conversión incluyendo el formato 0000:00:00 00:00:00

Answer (score 0):

Cuando se embebe el SQL en un código programado suelen aparecer incidentes que nunca se presentan en el SQL puro.

Tu código a nivel SQL estaría correcto si y sólo si la variable "IdLibroObtenidoDetalle" realmente contiene algo. Si esa variable contiene un Null, o viene vacía el resultado sería una consulta así:

```
SELECT * FROM detallepedido WHERE Libros_IdLibro =  AND FechaDevolucion IS NULL
```

Te recomiendo debuggear en detalle esa linea en tu programa. Es posible que la variable esté sin cargar o anulandose. Sin ver el resto del código de C# es difícil saberlo.

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que muestra el error no puede convertir el valor de DateTime de SQL con el del sistema.. Hace tiempo tuve ese problema y lo había "solucionado" guardando el dato con formato string..

Comment: donde guardas como string en la declaración de la BD o en el codigo c#??

Comment: Por lo que se ve la consulta si la ejecuta el problema es que ese mismo campo fecha es nulo en el regreso y no lo estas convirtiendo reader.IsDBNull(1) ? null : reader.GetString(reader.("FechaDevolucion")),

Comment: lo guardaba y lo trataba como tal.. luego si necesitaba hacer cuentas los convertía.. y al tratar como string buscaba el null como ""..